# tensorflow 2.5x slower than pytorch on vgg16 architecture

Tags: tensorflow

So I'm trying to get into tensorflow and liking it so far.

Today I upgraded to cuda 8, cudnn 5.1 and tensorflow 0.12.1. Using a Maxwell Titan X GPU.

Using the following short code of loading the pretrained vgg16:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import slim
from tensorflow.contrib.slim import nets

tf.reset_default_graph()
input_images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224, 224, 3], 'image')
preds = nets.vgg.vgg_16(input_images, is_training=False)[0]
saver = tf.train.Saver()

config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True,
                        gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
saver.restore(sess, './vgg_16.ckpt')

_in = np.random.randn(16, 224, 224, 3).astype(np.float32)
```

I then time the forward pass :

```
%timeit sess.run(preds, feed_dict={input_images: _in})
```

I get 160ms per batch (forward pass only), which seems 2.5x slower than the respective configuration in torch according to [this benchmark](https://github.com/jcjohnson/cnn-benchmarks) (and also slower than [MatconvNet](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/pretrained/)).

The operations seem correctly assigned to the gpu, and the cuda libraries properly found, what else am I missing?

Edit : cudnn and cuda properly found

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX TITAN X
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.076
pciBusID 0000:04:00.0
Total memory: 11.92GiB
Free memory: 11.81GiB
```

Also the feeding does not seem to be the problem since replacing `input_images` by `tf.random_uniform((16, 224, 224, 3), maxval=255)`does not change the timing.

Edit 2: So I compared to the pytorch version running on the same machine and I get (batches of 16x224x224x3) :

- Resnet-50 : **pytorch 48ms** vs **tf 58 ms** (OK)
- VGG16 : **pytorch 65ms** vs **tf 160ms** (not OK)

Comment: What if you replace `_in` with `tf.random_uniform((16, 224, 224, 3), maxval=255)` and get rid of `feed_dict`?

Comment: Removed the `tf.placeholder` by the `tf.random_uniform` call, does not change the timing :-(

Comment: cudnn installed? It's also possible that this vgg implementation uses old/unoptimized versions of ops which would need some digging in timelines to catch

Comment: Looking at the code of my version (0.12.1 so not very old), `slim` operations fall back to `contrib.layers`'s. Looking at tensorboard the operations used are just `conv2D` (even for the fc part, that's how the model is implemented in `slim`) with `use_cudnn_on_gpu=True`, `maxPool`, `BiasAdd` and `relu`. So it's unlikely the problem would be here right? Don't know how to find where I messed up.

Comment: It's possible that this is how fast it's supposed to run. IE, Torch one could be optimized and whereas this one could be an unoptimized reference implementation

Comment: Actually you're right, it seems that the speed I should expect, I just tried with pytorch and got the same speed. Surprisingly I do not find a performance gap with other benchmarks with the resnet architectures, only with VGG16 both in pytorch and tf. *scratches his head* Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: So in the end I was missing the cudnn autotune in pytorch (which contrary to tf, is not active by default), so I still get a large gap. I have updated the question

Comment: maybe worth filing an issue with repro (one that doesn't use feed_dict). Since pytorch is just released, there may be some interest in matching its performance

Comment: Ok I will take care of it.

Comment: thanks, tracking issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested recently on cuda 9.0, tensorflow 1.9 and pytorch 0.4.1, the differences are now negligible for the same operations.

See [the proper timing here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7065#issuecomment-419461999).